# How to make 2 lidar lite v3 work with 1 Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, i2c, 1-wire

I'm using the code below, but I had no success.

I'm using this connection wire:
The photo of the Arduino doesn't show the SCL and SDA pins, but please consider that it has 2 SCL pins and 2 SDA pins in the places where I marked them in the image.

Both sensors are working, however they are mirroring each other's measurements.

That link is from the datasheet:
https://static.garmin.com/pumac/LIDAR_Lite_v3_Operation_Manual_and_Technical_Specifications.pdf

[image]

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LIDARLite.h>

#define LIDAR1_ADDRESS 0x62 // Endereço I2C do LIDAR Lite 1
#define LIDAR2_ADDRESS 0x63 // Endereço I2C do LIDAR Lite 2

LIDARLite lidar1; // Objeto para o LIDAR Lite 1
LIDARLite lidar2; // Objeto para o LIDAR Lite 2

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();        // Inicializa a biblioteca Wire (I2C)
  Serial.begin(115200);  // Inicializa a comunicação serial

  // Inicializa os objetos dos LIDARs
  lidar1.begin(LIDAR1_ADDRESS); // Inicialização do LIDAR Lite 1
  lidar2.begin(LIDAR2_ADDRESS); // Inicialização do LIDAR Lite 2
}

void loop() {
  int distance1 = lidar1.distance();
  int distance2 = lidar2.distance();

  // Exibe as medições dos LIDARs no Monitor Serial
  Serial.print("LIDAR 1: ");
  Serial.print(distance1);
  Serial.print(" cm | LIDAR 2: ");
  Serial.print(distance2);
  Serial.println(" cm");

  delay(500); // Intervalo entre as leituras
}
```

Comment: what does `mirroring each other's measurements` mean?

Comment: you connected one to I2C bus and the other to the SPI bus ... why don't you connect both sensors to the same bus?

Comment: *had no success* doesn't tell us much. What is actually happening? What is appearing in the serial monitor?

Comment: I agree with @jsotola - if these are I2C devices, why connect one to the SPI port? I2C devices can be connected in parallel.

Comment: @jsotola, I'm so sorry, I wasnt really clear. Let me try again, both sensors seem to be measuring , but when I place an obstacle in front of either of then, both show the same reading on the serial monitor.

Comment: @NickGammon both sensors seem to be measuring , but when I place an obstacle in front of either of then, both show the same reading on the serial monitor, and i need that both display individual readings.

Comment: @jsotola sorry, that arduino in the image is not the same as mine. My arduino has two scl a sda pins. Where you are seeing the ISCP pins actually has a scl and sda pins

Comment: I put these twoaddress but im not sure if they are rigth. how can i get theses address?

Comment: I put the wire example to get the address, but the serial monitor only show me the "device found at address 0x62 "

Comment: Is the address of both Lidar Modules configurable and did you configure them on the boards (hardware)? If not it is possible that both listen and react to both of the addresses simultanously and then I2C transports the superposition of the bits from both devices to the arduino which then gets the same (possibly wrong) values independent of which device it tries to connect to.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer no, I didn't any configuration on the hardware, I just wire like the image and put the code.

Comment: What type of lidar device do you use (I mean the board not only the chip/sensor)? Do you have a link to its documentation? How did you know which addresses are appropriate? Have you a link to the docs of the used Arduino Library (LIDARlite). If you read the docs you might find the answers yourself. If not, show us the links; I mean add them to your question and you increase the chance, that someone invests more time and may help you.

Comment: @GUSTAVOTELES You haven't answered my question. You say "both sensors seem to be measuring", on your diagram you show one connected to the SPI port. This won't work. If the diagram is completely wrong, fix it or remove it. You are using I2C addresses 0x62 and 0x63. If you haven't configured the hardware they will both be responding to 0x62, which would account for the same readings. There appears to be an option to change the address, according to the datasheet. *The I2C address can be changed from its default value.* Have you done that?

Comment: *My arduino has two scl a sda pins.* - Don't post a photo which shows something completely different from reality. That just confuses everyone. Either photograph your own setup with your phone and upload it, or just sketch a circuit diagram.

Comment: @NickGammon You are sure I just changed the diagram for the real that I'm using, actually I didn't understand how to configure the hardware.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer I just added the link of documentation, On page 5 of the datasheet has the instruction to change, but didn't understand properly how do that.

Comment: Maybe my page didn't refresh, I see it now.

Comment: Run the I2C scanner described [here](http://gammon.com.au/i2c) - if that only shows one device, then naturally it will only give one reading. If not, please amend your question to show what the results are.

Comment: @NickGammon I used aTCA9548A multiplexer and I solved the addressing problem.

Comment: @NickGammon I appreciate  a lot your support, thank you.

Comment: Please make your own answer to this question and describe how you solved it, so as to help future people with the same problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If these are the Garmin Lidar Lite V3, here is a [link to their data sheet.](https://static.garmin.com/pumac/LIDAR_Lite_v3_Operation_Manual_and_Technical_Specifications.pdf) On page 5 of the datasheet you'll find instructions for configuring their I2C addresses. If you haven't already done that, it's quite likely that both devices are replying at once to the same query.

If you have done that already, please update your question with that and any other relevant data - such as the manufacturer, if I got that wrong, add any configuration changes you've made.